# AngularJS data binding checkboxes to object if checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON object which I am repeating with ng-repeat, the keys are strings, and the values are an array. I am listing each of the values as a checkbox. I would like to create a second object which contains a list of only the checkboxes that are checked. I want to preserve the structure of the object with keys and values.

I'm unsure how to bind this to a model properly so that the structure is preserved.

http://jsfiddle.net/NDFc2/3/

This is my HTML

```
<h3 >Dynamic data binding in AngularJS</h3>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller" class="container">
    <h4>Inputs</h4>
    <ul ng-repeat="(parent, values) in inputs">
        <span>{{parent}} : </span>
        <li ng-repeat="value in values"><label>{{value}}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="output[parent]" ng-checked="output[parent]" value="value" >                               
            </input></label>
        </li>
    </ul>    

    <h4>Outputs</h4>
    <ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in inputs">
        <li>
            {{key}} : {{output[key]}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my JS

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.output = {};
    $scope.inputs = {'category': ['one','two','three'], 'color':['blue','green']};
}
```

Is there some simple way to do this? I have the feeling that I'm missing something minor and this will all work nicely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My examples have your angular logic in the recommended syntax (non-global). There were also several issues with your markup that I have corrected.

In this example, `ng-model="x"` is a placeholder that I don't use, but `ng-model` must be present or an error is thrown. I am using `ng-change` to handle the link between the checkboxes and `$scope.outputs`.

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AkeZiSI/2/edit)

**Markup:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h3 >Dynamic data binding AngularJS</h3>
  <h4>Inputs</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(typeKey, typeVal) in inputs">
      <span>{{typeKey}} : </span>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="value in typeVal">
          <label>{{value}}
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              ng-model="x"
              ng-change="setOutput(typeKey, $index, value)"
            >
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>    

  <h4>Outputs</h4>
  <ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in inputs">
    <li>{{key}} : {{outputs[key]}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.outputs = {};
  $scope.inputs = {
    'category': ['one','two','three'],
    'color':['blue','green']
  };
  $scope.setOutput = function(typeKey, $index, value) {
    $scope.outputs[typeKey] = $scope.outputs[typeKey] || [];
    $scope.outputs[typeKey][$index] = value;
  };
});
```

### Another Solution

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AkeZiSI/1/edit)

First, I used `ng-init` to dynamically add the first-level properties from `inputs` to `outputs`. Then you just needed to set your `ng-model` and `ng-checked` properties to the correct location in `outputs`.

**Markup:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h3 >Dynamic data binding AngularJS</h3>
  <h4>Inputs</h4>
  <ul>
    <li 
      ng-repeat="(typeKey, typeVal) in inputs"
      ng-init="outputs[typeKey] = outputs[typeKey] || {}">
      <span>{{typeKey}} : </span>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="value in typeVal">
          <label>{{value}}
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              ng-model="outputs[typeKey][value]"
              ng-checked="outputs[typeKey][value]"
              value="outputs[typeKey][value]"
            >
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>    

  <h4>Outputs</h4>
  <ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in inputs">
    <li>{{key}} : {{outputs[key]}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.outputs = {};
  $scope.inputs = {
    'category': ['one','two','three'],
    'color':['blue','green']
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks @m59, both these solutions are great. The first one's output was what I'm really looking for, just an array of text, but the only thing is how does the item get removed when unchecked?

Comment: @EliteOctagon This will do it. http://jsbin.com/AkeZiSI/4/edit By the way, the cleanest way to do this is to scrap `ng-change` and `ng-model` altogether, then write your own directive, passing the input and output via attributes, then setting up your own $watch to handle the change (via similar logic to what I have in my function).

Comment: Per Angular's documentation 
"Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior."

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind to the value for the parent, as checkboxes don't work like that. Here's an example:

```
<h3 >Dynamic data binding in AngularJS</h3>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller" class="container">
    <h4>Inputs</h4>
    <ul ng-repeat="(parent, values) in inputs">
        <span>{{parent}} : </span>
        <li ng-repeat="value in values"><label>{{value}}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="output[parent][value]" ng+checked="output[parent][value]" value="value" >                               
            </input></label>
        </li>
    </ul>    

    <h4>Outputs</h4>
    <ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in inputs">
        <li>
            {{key}} : {{output[key]}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And in the controller create the keys beforehand

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.output = { 'category': {}, color: {} };
    $scope.inputs = {'category': ['one','two','three'], 'color':['blue','green']};
}
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/5eeVc/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this plunk, i have handled two different scenarios. Just sharing it as a knowledge article

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GxCRO4hVD03HShLMzsIH?p=preview)

```
      <h3>First Scenario <small>Handling JSON source </small></h3>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <h4>Available options</h4>
        <div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
          <mark>{{item.name}}</mark>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="modelContainer[$index].checked" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <h4 class="text-success">Selected options</h4>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="item in modelContainer | filter: {checked:true}">
            {{item.item.name}} <a href="#" class="cl" ng-click="uncheck(item.item.id)">X</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <p class="text-danger">itemList</p>
  <code>{{itemList}}</code>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="text-danger">modelContainer</p>
  <code>{{modelContainer}}</code>

  <hr>
  <h3>Second Scenario <small>Handling map Source </small></h3>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <h4>Available options</h4>
        <div ng-repeat="item in Maplist">
          <mark>{{item}}</mark>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="modelContainer1[$index].checked" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <h4 class="text-success">Selected options</h4>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="item in modelContainer1 | filter: {checked:true}">
            {{item.name}} <a href="#" class="cl" ng-click="uncheck1(item.id)">X</a>
          </li>`enter code here`
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```